# Steps to change Default Salesforce Client Certificate

Tags: api-client-certificate

Yesterday I received an email from Salesforce that [the default salesforce client certificate will expire on Aug 7, 2017](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Default-Certificate-to-Retire-on-August-7-2017&language=en_US&eid=ss-tc). In the required actions, the article said:

> 1. If you don’t have an existing self-managed certificate, create one.
> 2. Update the API Client Certificate with your new certificate.

So, I created a 'Self-Signed Certificate' and updated it as the 'API Client Certificate'. Is that all needed? Has anyone else done this? I'm assuming the 'Self-Signed Certificate' is qualified as the Self-Managed certificate. Our org doesn't have Single Sign-On or Outbound Messages. It uses Ajax Proxy, getContent() and getContentAsPDF().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user had this same issue and he found the [**solution**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/149027/17228) from Steven Lawrence from Salesforce. What I've done is sufficient enough for this change. 'Self-Signed Certificate' is qualified as the Self-Managed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this recently when the production and sandbox environments all were expiring. The easiest way to do a new one is to first copy down the name and machine name of the current one, then rename it "..._old" then create a new one immediately with the same name as the original. This fixes issues around apps or SSO services that were referencing the old cert.