# Default Certificate Expiration, is action required for getContent calls to Visualforce Pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, certificates

I maintain an iOS app that uses the Salesforce Mobile SDK. My app uses the SDK to make a POST request to an Apex class. That apex class calls getContent on a Visualforce page. I have checked the request headers for this call, and the 'ciphersuite' header has a value. According to the docs, this means that the call does use HTTPS.

I recently received an email, essentially saying the same as this link:

[Default Certificate to retire on Aug 7, 2017](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Default-Certificate-to-Retire-on-August-7-2017&language=en_US&eid=ss-tc)

It is unclear to me from these notes, whether or not any action is required on my part to ensure everything still functions normally after Aug 7. Is any action required by me in relation to this getContent call?

The notes say:

> ** Only customers that are calling out to HTTPS endpoints that request or require a client certificate are affected.

I have verified that this call uses HTTPS, I guess then the question that remains is: does the Visualforce page "request or require a client certificate". I'm unclear about what this means and/or how to verify it.

The class that calls getContent uses API 31.0, and further research has discovered the following:

> getContent is treated as a callout in API version 34.0 and later.

which would seem to imply that this Visualforce page call is not a "call out", and so may not be affected by the default cert expiration?

Comment: See also: [Question regarding default Salesforce client certificate being retired](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148213/question-regarding-default-salesforce-client-certificate-being-retired)

Comment: So, as long as the class is maintained at a version lower than 34.0, it should be ok not to use certificates? It would be nice to have a step-by-step in order to prepare for when version 33 isn't available anymore. I'm still not certain on what to do to say to my client that everything is ok.

Comment: I'm guessing (and it's really just a guess) that getContent to VF pages below API 34.0 is probably safe. It may be safe on 34 also, but I wouldn't count on that. I too am waiting on more authoritative confirmation. We may have our SF reps pass on this Q to their dev team if nothing appears here.

Comment: You can still save classes with API Version 10.0 if you are so inclined...they'll never drop support for version 33. It's also fairly straightforward to prove whether or not `getContent` at that version counts as a callout.